# I get an error in PostgreSql: number of referencing and referenced columns for foreign key disagree

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

I'm creating a table, but I get this error:

> - number of referencing and referenced columns for foreign key disagree.

I don't know how to solve it. I think that it may be a problem with declaring 3 foreign keys, but, I'm not sure about it.

What is the problem?

```sql
Create table Trasllat
(
Data Date,
Codi_Empleat Integer,
Nom_agencia Varchar(30),
Data_fi Date,
Primary key (Data, Codi_Empleat),
Foreign key (Data) references Data on delete cascade,
Foreign key (Codi_empleat) references Empleat on delete cascade
Foreign key (Nom_agencia) references Agencia on delete cascade
);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because you are not specifying the specific column name of the table to which it should reference to. Your Foreign key declaration should look like below. Notice the part, `references Empleat(column_name)` it says that column `Codi_empleat` references to `Empleat` tables `column_name` column.

```
Foreign key (Data) references Trasllat(Data) on delete cascade,
Foreign key (Codi_empleat) references Empleat(column_name) on delete cascade
Foreign key (Nom_agencia) references Agencia(column_name) on delete cascade
```

Check [Postgres Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-fk.html) to get more information on the same.

Comment: This solved the problem, but I get another error:there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "agencia".

Comment: @blaclotus, that's because the column you are referencing in `agencia` table is not a primary key/unique key. You can't create FK on a non key column. Make sure the column you are referencing is a key column.

Comment: May be the problem caused because in table "agencia" i have 2 Primary Keys?////////

Create table Agencia
(
Nom_agencia Varchar(30),
Nom_ciutat Varchar(30),
Adreca Varchar(30),
Telefin Number(9),
Primary key (Nom_agencia, Nom_ciutat),
Foreign key (Nom_ciutat) references Ciutat on delete cascade
);

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. To reference `Agencia` you must refer to both the PK columns and that to with two field in your Trasllat table like `Foreign key (Nom_agencia, other_column) references Agencia(Nom_agencia, Nom_ciutat)`